# Norm of a linear functional, how do we find it?

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $L:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional with $E=\{f \in C([a,b]); f(a)=f(b)=0\}$ and $$L(f) = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx.$$ Suppose we have the norm $\|f\| = \int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx$. I need to find the norm of $L$ in $(E,\|\cdot\|).$ I saw some definitions (the textbook I'm using doesn't give one) and i find that the norm is $$\|L\| = \sup_{f \in E} \frac{\|Lf\|}{\|f\|}$$ with $f \ne 0$. I have two questions: We have some intuition to use this and, in my case, should i just do $$\|L\|=\sup_{f \in E} \frac{|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx|}{\int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx}?$$

Cause this doesn't seem to use $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Any help, links or textbook are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The proper definition of the norm would be
$$
\|L\| = \sup_{f \in E, f \neq 0} \frac {\left| \int_a^b f(x) dx \right|}{\|f\|} = \sup_{f \in E, f \neq 0} \frac {\left| \int_a^b f(x) dx \right|}{\int_a^b |f(x)| dx},
$$
so it depends on what norm you choose on the space $C[a,b]$ as well. The condition $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ is incorporated, because the supremum is taken over nonzero functions in $E$.

Note that
$$
\left| \int_a^b f(x) dx \right| \leq \int_a^b |f(x)| dx
$$
for all functions $f$. Hence
$$
\forall f \in E \setminus\{0\} : \frac {\left| \int_a^b f(x) dx \right|}{\int_a^b |f(x)| dx} \leq 1 \implies \|L\| \leq 1.
$$
Conversely, if $f(x) = (x - a)(b-x)$, then $f \in E \setminus \{0\}$, and it's positive, so $|f(x)| = f(x)$. Hence, $\|f\| = |Lf|$, and we get that $\|L\| \geq 1$.

Together, this proves $\|L\| = 1$.

Comment: Oh, i edited the first part. Thank you very much! Just to clarify my idea, i have a similar question but with $\|f\|=\text{max} |f(x)|, x \in [a,b]$. I find $\|L\|=b-a$, this makes sense? Again, thank you!

Comment: I believe that's right.

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of integral is $$|L(f)|=\left|\int^b_af(x)dx\right|\leqslant\int^b_a|f(x)|dx=\|f\|_{E}$$ so $\|L\|=\sup_{f\in E}\frac{|L(f)|}{\|f\|_E}\leqslant 1$. Can you prove that there is a $f\in E$ such that $|L(f)|=\|f\|_E$? (Hint: What if $f$ is positive?)